# Using FFTW3 Fortran library in MacOS

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, gfortran, macos-sierra, fftw

I am getting the following error while trying to compile a Fortran program with gfortran and FFTW3 library. The program however compiles successfully with the Intel compiler ifort.

**Error**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__gfortran_os_error_at", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccAVlghr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

**Compile Command**

```
gfortran -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib pois.f90 -lfftw3 -lm
```

`pois.f90` is the program which contains FFTW3 commands to solve a Poisson equation through Fourier transform.

The equivalent C program also compiles and executes successfully. The FFTW3 statements are inserted in `Poisson.f90` as per FFTW3 documents. The routine which uses FFTW3 commands is given below

```
subroutine fft_forward(j,f,Fr,Fi)
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  include 'fftw3.f03'
  double precision :: f(j),Fr(j),Fi(j)
  integer :: i,j
  type(C_PTR) :: plan
  complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) :: FF(j)

  plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(j,f,FF,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
  call fftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan,f,FF)
  call fftw_destroy_plan(plan)

  do i = 1,j
    Fr(i) = real(FF(i))/j
    Fi(i) = aimag(FF(i))/j
  enddo

  Fr = Fr/j; Fi = Fi/j
end
```

I also tried using a compiler flag `-lgfortran` but got the same error. Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions and note that this is not Fortran 90 but at least 2003. Does  your compiler compile simple programs? We have several  questions and answers about the same error on MacOS. How did you install gfortran? Homebrew? Which version is it? Please do try some very simple Fortran program.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава: `gfortran` uses the `.f90,f95,f03,f08` suffixes only to select free-form rather than fixed-form, not a specific standard; you can write F18 semantics _in fixed-form_ in a `.f` file if you really want. `ifort` similarly uses `.f90` only for free-form of any standard, making `.f90` a good choice to use for both compilers. But which build/package/install of gfortran is indeed a good thing to check here.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Still, this is not Fortran 90 code

Comment: Why does your error message lead you to believe the error is to do with FFTW3 routines … or even the subroutine shown?

Comment: Well, I routinely Fortran programs for my work with the same machine and with the same ```gfortran``` built, which are being compiled with ```gfortran``` and run successfully. The error comes ONLY with ```FFTW``` code. Which is why it led me to believe that this is particular to ```FFTW```.

Comment: Nevertheless, if you comment out the FFTW calls (and avoid other potential issues by simply replacing them by FF=f) does the program COMPILE? The error message seems to suggest the absent functions are called from MAIN (the PROGRAM unit), not from the subroutine here.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on what you did while installing `GNU Fortran`, `FFTW`, et al.

In my case, it works as expected.

I have `GNU Fortran` installed from sources: [gcc-9-2-0](https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/)

Then, I have built `FFTW` using my own installation of `GNU Fortran`

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local/fftw/fftw-3.3.10 CC=gcc-9.2.0 MPICC=mpicc F77=gfortran-9.2.0
make
make install
```

and then, I have compiled your sample using

```
gfortran-9.2.0 -I$HOME/opt/usr/local/fftw/fftw-3.3.10/include -L$HOME/opt/usr/local/fftw/fftw-3.3.10/lib -lfftw3 -lm -c simple.f90
```

I have also added short `_main` stuff like so to double check it links with the stuff

```
program main

   print *, 'Hello'

end program main
```

after building, it runs as expected

```
gfortran-9.2.0 -I$HOME/opt/usr/local/fftw/fftw-3.3.10/include -L$HOME/opt/usr/local/fftw/fftw-3.3.10/lib -lfftw3 -lm simple.f90 -o main
./main
 Hello
```

I guess you have sort of a messy `GNU Fortran` + `FFTW` installation.

Comment: Sure, the error is a linker error. And as I indicated in a comment, we had this error message several times before. Usually one neds to reinstall gfortran or some Mac specific stuff around command line tools and Xcode. I do not believe FFTW is relevant here at all, it is just a noise.

Comment: Well, I routinely Fortran programs for my work with the same machine and with the same ```gfortran``` built, which are being compiled with ```gfortran``` and run successfully. The error comes ONLY with ```FFTW``` code. Which is why it led me to believe that this is particular to ```FFTW```.